# How can I make a pandas dataframe out of multiple numpy arrays

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have 2 arrays as below that I want to be converted to dataframe columns:

```
arr1 = np.array([2, 4, 6, 8])
arr2 = np.array([3, 6, 9, 12])
df_from_arr = pd.DataFrame(data=[arr1, arr2])
print(df_from_arr)
```

Actual Output:

```
   0  1  2   3
0  2  4  6   8
1  3  6  9  12
```

Expected output:

```
   0  1 
0  2  4 
1  4  6
2  6  9
3  8  12
```

How can I get the expected output?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add T at the end

```
df_from_arr.T
Out[418]: 
   0   1
0  2   3
1  4   6
2  6   9
3  8  12
```

Or modify your input arrays

```
pd.DataFrame(np.hstack((arr1[:,None], arr2[:,None])))
Out[426]: 
   0   1
0  2   3
1  4   6
2  6   9
3  8  12
```

Answer (score 11):

You can transpose the DataFrame.

```
arr1 = np.array([2, 4, 6, 8])
arr2 = np.array([3, 6, 9, 12])
df_from_arr = pd.DataFrame(data=[arr1, arr2]).T
print(df_from_arr)

   0   1
0  2   3
1  4   6
2  6   9
3  8  12
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also do this:

```
arr1 = np.array([2, 4, 6, 8])
arr2 = np.array([3, 6, 9, 12])
df_from_arr = pd.DataFrame({0:arr1,1:arr2})
```